# Необходимо из одного активити передать значение переменной из другой активити, но второе активити его не видит

Tags: java, android

```
Activity1
...
    public int b = 0;
    public String S = "";
...
    public void counter(){
        b++;
        S = Integer.toString(b);
    }
...
Activity2
tvCounter.setText(S); //S - подчеркнуто красным цветом
```

Comment: да засунь в кэш значение и вытащи его из другой активи и не грей голову

Comment: спасибо за ответ, можно подробней?фрагмент кода, если не сложно

Comment: загугли sharedpref, примеров куча будет и строки и инт хранит

Comment: у тебя что int, string с идентификатором доступа public, так наследуй их, activity1 extends activity2, а activity2 extentds appcompatactivity

Comment: @iFr0z вы сейчас научите :). Между активити данные передаются через `Intent` и только так, иначе будут проблемы, так как никто не гарантирует существование активити, которая не находится на экране, как и ее полей - ваш способ прямая дорога к NPE

Comment: @pavlofff а ну это да, согласен)

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
startActivity(i);
```

В новой Activity, получите значения следующим образом:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
}
```

Comment: есть развернутый ответ

Comment: String data = "Эти данные необходимо передать";

`Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActitviy.class);
i.putExtra("testNameData", data);
startActivity(i);`


А во втором активити вызывается метод getIntent и по указанному ключу вытаскивается данные.
Например:
`String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("testNameData");`